# What is the cause of runtime error in the following code?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I have been solving this problem http://www.codechef.com/DEC13/problems/MARBLEGF/ and i am not getting why am getting runtime error again and again,can anyone please help me with this?
Thanks in advance..!!
Heres the code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long int n;
    long int q;
    int i,a,b,sum_temp=0,flag=0;
    char act[10];

    cin>>n;
    cin>>q;

    int array[n],temp[n],temp2[n];
    long int sum;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>temp[i];
        temp2[i]=0;
        array[i]=0;
    }
    while(q>0){
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            cin>>act[i];
        }
        act[3]='\0';
        a=act[1]-'0';
        b=act[2]-'0';
        if(act[0]=='S'){
            if(array[b]==0){
                for(i=0;i<=b;i++){
                    if(i>0){
                        array[i]=array[i-1]+temp[i];
                    }else{
                        array[i]=temp[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            sum_temp=0;
            for(i=a;i<=b && flag==1;i++){
                sum_temp=sum_temp+temp2[i];         
            }
            if(a>0){
                sum=(array[b]-array[a-1])+sum_temp;

            }
            else{
                sum=array[b]+sum_temp;
            }

            cout<<sum<<endl;

        }
        else if(act[0]=='G'){
            temp2[a]=b;
            flag=1;
        }
        else if(act[0]=='T'){
            temp2[a]=-b;
            flag=1;
        }
        q--;
    }



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: To increase your chances of getting an answer I suggest you format your code better and try to describe the error more precisely

Comment: http://codepad.org/cKo6ldBa

Comment: Kindly provide a compilable code.

Comment: You haven't actually tested this before submitting, have you? You're only reading three characters for each action, so there's no way anything could work with any test case, ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

As per the link you provided, the range of N is `2 ≤ N ≤ 1000000`.
Hence as suggested by @Retired Ninja, there is a possibility that you may be getting stack overflow.

Solution: Use a vector.

Among other things, this is not valid C++:

```
cin>>n;
cin>>q;

int array[n],temp[n],temp2[n];
```

Here n should be a compile time constant. Better is to use

```
std::vector<int> array( n );
```

One reason as to why you are getting run-time error is you maybe accessing out of bounds array:

```
b=act[2]-'0';
if(act[0]=='S'){
  if(array[b]==0){
```

How do you know here that b is less then array size?

I suggest you run it through a debugger.

Comment: But how would that solve the problem? If the code has a runtime error, it compiles, which means a VLA extension is available.

Comment: How big do those array end up being?  Quite possibly a stack overflow.